# ld: i386 architecture of input file `lib/kernel.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I am attempting to compile a kernel written in c++ using a cross compiler, but whenever I try to link the files it throws the error above. There's been questions like this but none of them have provided a working solution.

[ld file](https://pastebin.com/EnyJxyJe)

[make file](https://pastebin.com/58yaiRQE) (I call make kernel, make buildimg, and make run in that order)

Full output of ld command:

```
ld: i386 architecture of input file `lib/kernel.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
make: *** [Makefile:33: link] Error 1
```

gcc version:

```
i686-elf-gcc (GCC) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

[Code](https://github.com/MorticiaGrey/XOS)

Upon further inspection it's throwing this error because it's compiling the kernel to `32 bit intel 80386` and everything else to `64 bit x86-64`, which is confusing because the exact same command is run for both except that the file it's compiling is different

Comment: If you're using a cross-compiler, shouldn't you be using a cross-linker to match it?  Do you have an `i686-elf-ld`?

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm not sure I'm very new to this stuff, I followed [this tutorial](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler)

Comment: If you installed binutils the way the tutorial says, you should have `/home/morticia/opt/cross/bin/i686-elf-ld`.  Try changing `LD = ld` to `LD = /home/morticia/opt/cross/bin/i686-elf-ld` instead.

Comment: @NateEldredge it says 'no such file or directory', I tried looking in the compiled binutils and opt/cross/bin/ but on first glance I don't see a file named that

Comment: @NateEldredge it looks like opt/cross/bin has an 'ld', but when I try with that it throws 'target elf64-x86-64 not found'